# how to add map data to cloud firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add the name of the user as a map containing 'firstName' and 'lastName'. I already have the user model and the name model, here is the code:

**name_model.dart**

```
class Name {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;

  Name({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
    };
  }

  Name.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> nameMap)
      : firstName = nameMap['firstName'],
        lastName = nameMap['lastName'];
}
```

**user_model.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ukk_backup/models/name_model.dart';

class User {
  final String? docId;
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final Name name;

  User({
    this.docId,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.name,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'docId': docId,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'name': name.toMap(),
      };
  User.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc)
      : docId = doc.id,
        email = doc['email'],
        password = doc['password'],
        phoneNumber = doc['phoneNumber'],
        name = Name.fromMap(doc['name']);
}
```

when I pressed the register button I want all the data to be saved in cloud firestore, including the name with the map type. This is the **onPressed**:

```
onPressed: (() async {
 if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
   DatabaseService service = DatabaseService();
   User user = User(
     email: emailController.text,
     password: passwordController.text,
     phoneNumber: phoneNumberController.text,
     name: , //what to type?
   );
   setState(() {
     _isLoading = true;
   });
   await service.addUser(user);
   setState(() {
   _isLoading = false;
   });
  }
}),
```

If you found some of my code is not correct or you found the solution, please tell me. Thank you.

**Edit:**

database_services.dart

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:ukk_backup/models/user_model.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  addUser(User userData) async {
    await _firestore.collection('users').add(userData.toMap());
  }

  updateUser(User userData) async {
    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userData.docId)
        .update(userData.toMap());
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser(String documentId) async {
    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(documentId).delete();
  }

  Future<List<User>> retrieveUser() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
        await _firestore.collection('users').get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => User.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: add code for database service

Comment: @griffins I already added the database_services.dart

Comment: @TheUltimateOptimist can you give me some tutorials I can follow for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your question first. Your DataBaseService class looks ok to me. So if I am right the only problem you have is that you do not know how to add the name to the UserObject. If that's the essence of your question then that is very easy:

```
onPressed: (() async {
 if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
   DatabaseService service = DatabaseService();
   User user = User(
     email: emailController.text,
     password: passwordController.text,
     phoneNumber: phoneNumberController.text,
     name: Name(firstName: firstNameController.text, lastName: lastNameController.text),
   );
   setState(() {
     _isLoading = true;
   });
   await service.addUser(user);
   setState(() {
   _isLoading = false;
   });
  }
}),
```

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer because I already decided not to use the user_model but it doesn't mean that I'm not gonna try your answer. I'm going to your use your code on my next project. Thank you for answering